# this.handleChange.bind(this) and render use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecma

I got this code from react bootstrap website  https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/  I will like to know the use of the following in the code

- this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
- The use of making the `value` in `this.state = {
    value: ''
  }; }`
  empty
- The use of setting the `validationState` attribute in `validationState={this.getValidationState()}`
- And the use of setting two renders, why not just one render and is it possible to set more than one render

  ```
      class FormExample extends React.Component {
      constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

       this.state = {
     value: ''
     };
     }

     getValidationState() {
     const length = this.state.value.length;
     if (length > 10) return 'success';
     else if (length > 5) return 'warning';
     else if (length > 0) return 'error';
      return null;
      }

      handleChange(e) {
      this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
      }

       render() {
       return (
       <form>
       <FormGroup
       controlId="formBasicText"
    validationState={this.getValidationState()}
  >
    <ControlLabel>Working example with validation</ControlLabel>
    <FormControl
      type="text"
      value={this.state.value}
      placeholder="Enter text"
      onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
    <FormControl.Feedback />
    <HelpBlock>Validation is based on string length.</HelpBlock>
  </FormGroup> </form>
      );
      }
      }

  render(<FormExample />);
  ```

Comment: stop downvoting , this question is totally valid!

Comment: Am learning, i also use stack overflow to get better on things i don't understand

Comment: Please recommend a site that can aid my learning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this): This is to make it
   so you can use the variable "this" inside of handlechange()
2. By setting a blank value, this key will not be empty in the future
   if you try to reference it without a value being set
3. validationState is being passed into FormGroup as a property
4. The renders are not in the same class so the FormExample is being
   rendered by something else outside it.

Hope that helps

Comment: What's the use of setting the validationState as a property

Comment: The FormGroup element doesn't know what the state of validation is unless you pass it in (https://medium.com/react-tutorials/react-properties-ef11cd55caa0). This means that inside of the FormGroup you can check this.props.validationState and see if any of the elements are in an error state. You will also frequently see syntax that looks like { validationState, someOtherProp } = this.props; This is known as destructuring and is equivalent to validationState = this.props.validationState; someOtherProp = this.props.someOtherProp; (https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/).